# Flutter Shared Preference not returning bool correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, static, boolean, sharedpreferences

I am trying to show a screen only the first time the user opens it. For that I build that helper-function:

```
 static Future<bool> measureCorrectlyWasNotShownBefore() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _seen = prefs.getBool(_measureCorrectlyKey) ?? false;

    if (_seen) {
      return true;
    } else {
      await prefs.setBool(_measureCorrectlyKey, true);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

I would like to use it like this:

```
if (LocalStorageService.measureCorrectlyWasNotShownBefore()) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

However Flutter is complaining:

> Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.
> Try changing the condition.

How can I fix this? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your `measureCorrectlyWasNotShownBefore` is returning a `Future<bool>` not a `bool`. And hence you cant give that inside an `if` where `if` is expecting a `bool` type.

You need to wait for that Future to complete and then check with the if statement.

```
final result =
      await LocalStorageService.measureCorrectlyWasNotShownBefore();
if(result){

}
```